# iPad Splash screen Jumps / Cutoff

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

[image]

As you can see in the video above, initially the bottom part of my splashscreen is cutoff but then it adjusts to the correct position. Any idea on what the problem here is?

I am using these for my splash screens:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~universal~comany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~universal~comcom.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@3x~universal~anycom.png" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@3x~universal~comany.png" />
</platform>
```

Comment: http://blog.ionicframework.com/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/ did you use `ionic cordova resources` to generate the splash screens? that is a more up to date command than `ionic resources`

Comment: Can you please show me your original splash screen image which have 2800x2800 resolution